# JavaScript animation very buggy

Tags: javascript, animation

So I have a very small, insignificant site i'm working on. [my website](http://www.crouseox.com/chucksef/sample_gallery/index.php) If you click on the grey-ish bar at the bottom, it will animate a sort of eased-in for me to use in the future to edit info i put together on various pictures or whatever i decide i want to put up there.

my code for the animation is: (**edited to reflect changes**)

```
function animateForm(startPosition,endPosition,firstKey,keyInterval) 
{
    if(currentKey != lastKey)
    {
        animationPointer =( .5 * Math.sin((currentKey * (Math.PI/totalKeys)) - (Math.PI/2))) + .5;
        currentPosition = (animationPointer)*endPosition;
        bottomForm.style.bottom = currentPosition + "px";
        currentKey=currentKey+(keyInterval*1);
    }
    else 
    {
        clearInterval(int);
        int=0;
    }
}
```

SOLVED! The problem was that I was multiplying the "animation pointer" (a decimal from 0 to 1 indicating the progress in the animation) by the "end position," and if the animation was aiming for an end position of "0," This set my form's position immediately to the "hide" position, and things asploded from there.

What i needed to do multiply the pointer by the maximum height the form could reach so that on its descent it could gradually return a smaller and smaller value to the "currentPosition" variable.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't/you don't want to use, for example, jQuery?

Comment: Immediately: `totalKeys` is not declared. Put your code in strict mode and run JSHint on it.

Comment: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) is a great way to test and share your JavaScript.

Comment: Please put the relevant part of your problem only..not the entire code.

Comment: If you're looking for smooth animations, you really should consider a library, there are so many great ones out there that doing this yourself makes no sense. If you don't want the overhead of jQuery you could use something like [**GSAP**](http://www.greensock.com/gsap-js/) which is even smoother and with more options.

Comment: While others may be far better at answering your specific JavaScript questions than I, it looks to me like what you need is tweening and easing. Have you considered a third party package for this where they've already figured it all out? Greensock has some good frameworks for it : http://www.greensock.com/get-started-js/.

Comment: Thanks all, the reason i'm not using a library is that i'm just learning js and I wanted to try to give myself a little experiment to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're never clearing the `setInterval` between animations. Simply typing `clearInterval;` doesn't do anything. You need to store the ID that's returned from `setInterval()`, and then pass it to a call to `clearInterval();`.

Because you're not clearing, those original intervals are still running and still trying to operate on the same variables.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I looked up clearInterval() for more information on how it works and i think i now understand it a whole lot better.

However, making the above changes to my js didn't really do anything  for the integrity of the animation. Were you suggesting that this change would fix my problem or was it just a side note?

Comment: I think it should fix it, but I don't have time to dig in too deep, Basically you need to make sure that the return result from `setInterval` is assigned to a variable, and that the `clearInterval()` is passed that same value. In your updated code, I can't tell if `int` has the correct value.